# Esper - Using user-defined function in filter expressions in patterns

Tags: java, filter, esper, complex-event-processing

I don't understand why I am unable to do this:

```
select * from pattern [every A = EventA -> EventB(myFunction(A.property))]
```

From Esper documentation :"All expressions can be used in filters, including static method invocations that return a boolean value".

If I don't try to reference properties from the first matched event (EventA) and instead I only try to pass properties from EventB to myFunction, it works OK.

The error I get is this :

```
com.espertech.esper.client.EPException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processWrappedEvent(EPRuntimeImpl.java:464)
at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processEvent(EPRuntimeImpl.java:437)
at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.sendEvent(EPRuntimeImpl.java:196)
.................
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at com.espertech.esper.epl.expression.ExprIdentNodeEvaluatorImpl.evaluate(ExprIdentNodeEvaluatorImpl.java:30)
at com.espertech.esper.epl.expression.ExprDotEvalStaticMethod.get(ExprDotEvalStaticMethod.java:133)
at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterParamIndexEquals.matchEvent(FilterParamIndexEquals.java:28)
at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterParamIndexEquals.matchEvent(FilterParamIndexEquals.java:51)
at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterHandleSetNode.matchEvent(FilterHandleSetNode.java:97)
at com.espertech.esper.filter.EventTypeIndex.matchType(EventTypeIndex.java:171)
at com.espertech.esper.filter.EventTypeIndex.matchEvent(EventTypeIndex.java:109)
at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterServiceImpl.evaluate(FilterServiceImpl.java:75)
at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processMatches(EPRuntimeImpl.java:911)
at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processWrappedEvent(EPRuntimeImpl.java:459)
... 30 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the event type information for EventA and the actual event object do not match so Esper is not able to retrieve the property value. Try to compare the type information and actual object that is sent in.

Comment: Using a different event instead of EventA doesn't change anything. It looks to me as if you don't have access to the previous matched event in that context (static method invocation in a filter).

Comment: Works fine online. See http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html. Copy&paste this: create schema EventA(property string); create schema EventB(property string);
@Name('Out') select * from pattern [every A = EventA -> EventB(Boolean.parseBoolean(A.property))]   ....... and the sequence  EventA={property="true"}
EventB={property="true"}